# how to rotate back the flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have made three flex box. and add a transform that rotate 90 degree when hover over. but i want to see that it rotate back when i put my mouse from the box. so here is the code.

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#flex-container :hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgb(123, 251, 3);
  padding: 1px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 1000ms;
}

.flex-item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-item1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 166, 6);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-item2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(248, 71, 7);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item1"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
</div>
```

it only rotate 90 degree and stop. but i want to see that it rotate back 90 degree when i put away my mouse.
i am a very new learner please consider my mistakes in language. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your transition from your hover to your `flex-items`, then when you take your mouse out, it will transition back.

I would also make use of a shared class for your flex items so you are not repeating your css multiple times

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: 1000ms;
}

.flex-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgb(123, 251, 3);
  padding: 1px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.flex-item--1 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.flex-item--2 {
  background-color: rgb(246, 166, 6);
}
.flex-item--3 {
  background-color: rgb(248, 71, 7);
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item--1"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item--2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item--3"></div>
</div>
```